# How do I find in jQuery whether a p:selectBooleanCheckbox has been checked or not

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, selectbooleancheckbox

I need to know how to iterate through a list of primefaces p:selectBooleanCheckbox elements and find out rather or not they have been checked. I have found out how to find them but not how to actually get rather or not they are true or false, I was wondering if anyone here would be able to assist with this.

In as little code as possible this is what I am currently doing to get the actual element returned to me, I have used the jquery :checked as well as .val() and a few other methods but none seem to work. I have also tried sifting through the code in the element object in the console looking for anything that stands out and I haven't been able to find anything either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<body>
    <ui:composition template="./../../WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 350px;">
                <p:outputLabel for="coop_sent" value="CO-OP Sent"/>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox name="coop_sent" styleClass="pc"     widgetVar="coop_sent" id="coop_sent" value="#{editProjectsBean.pc.co_opSen}"/>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    for (var propertyName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
                        if (PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof     PrimeFaces.widget.SelectBooleanCheckbox){
                            if (PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].widgetVar ===     'coop_sent') {
                                console.log($('PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].widgetVar.coop_sent')); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are you planning on searching it? in the rendered html? or in your backing bean?

Comment: @Fritz, I plan on doing it in the rendered html I am going to use the results to display a button after all the check boxes are selected, I could do it in the backing bean but I don't feel as it that is dynamic enough for what I am pursuing.

Comment: `template="./../../WEB-INF/template.xhtml"` Get rid of that `../` nonsense. It's always relative to the web root, so just use `template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"`.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't  aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

As to the concrete question, the associated widget object has just a `isChecked()` function.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox widgetVar="foo" ... />
```

```
var checked = PF("foo").isChecked();
```

See also [this blog](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/) for an introduction on how to explore the widget var and all available functions.

As to the actual functional requirement, the question is a bit confusing and ambiguous as you seem to be interested in scanning through multiple checkbox components, but the jQuery code snippet is actually interested in only one. I guess that you're actually including this code snippet multiple times in an iteration, but you faced the problem that you ultimately found only one `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` widget in `PrimeFaces.widgets` which made you to ask this overly generic question.

You should be suffixing the widget var name with e.g. the iteration index or so.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox widgetVar="foo_#{index}" ... />
```

A (better) alternative is to just give them all a common style class and traverse the HTML DOM tree instead. There's a hidden `<input type="checkbox">` which you could just grab and check the `checked` state.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox ... styleClass="pc" />
```

```
if ($(".ui-chkbox.pc input[type=checkbox]:checked").length) {
    // At least one is checked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I've tried, using this tag:

`<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.checkbox}" styleClass="test"/>`

the rendered html is this:

```
<div id="tableForm:j_id868283402_33c0fe0b" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget test">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="tableForm:j_id868283402_33c0fe0b_input" type="checkbox" name="tableForm:j_id868283402_33c0fe0b_input">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

toggling the checkbox would just replace the `ui-icon-blank` to `ui-icon-check` in the `<span>` tag and vice versa.

I added `styleClass="test"` in the `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` tag. I think you can just use this `.test .ui-chkbox-box > span` to select the `<span>` tag and determine the values in its class attribute whether it's blank or checked.